# scrollTop only scrolls down

Tags: jquery, scrollto, scrolltop

I'm trying to make a div scroll to its top, but for some reason it won't work.

This code works, and scrolls to the bottom of a div inside my wrapper:

```
$('#wrapper').animate({ scrollTop: $("#innerbox").height() }, 5000);
```

And this code works if I use Ariel Flesler's jQuery.ScrollTo plugin:

```
$('div#wrapper').scrollTo( '+=100px', 8000 );
```

But if I try to set the first code to the element's `.offset().top` or the second one to `'-=100px'` instead of `'+=100px'` it doesn't work, just does nothing...

What could be causing this?

[Update: seems like I'm using the code better now, but still no luck getting it to work in my JQtouch application, [so I've posted relevant code here](http://groups.google.com/group/jqtouch/browse_thread/thread/b1edc50ce6eed02e?pli=1)]

Comment: Note: I'm using this in a quite complex environment (JQtouch application with this kind of tabbar: http://groups.google.com/group/jqtouch/msg/3a80fa286b213234), but since there aren't a lot of people using it the same way, I think there's a better chance of solving this if I just get ideas of what could be causing the problem

Comment: "better" compared to what? Providing an actual testcase that demonstrates the issue? Heaven forbid.

Comment: Providing a testcase would require a lot of time, which wouldn't be necessary if there's something elementary I'm missing (which I'm hoping is the case). Naturally I cannot post the entire source-code of my app, but if needed I will take the time to create a testcase.... thanks:)

Comment: @Tomalak we can't all be as great as you! :)

Comment: @Adam: If you want us to spend time solving your problem for you, we expect you to spend time doing some basic debugging and narrowing down your issue to a testcase first. It's only polite. (And usually it will help you to find the problem on your own before resorting to asking others for help!) "The entire source-code of [your] app" is absolutely _not_ what we want to see here.

Answer (score 2):

What scrollTop will do is set the scroll bar to the provided offset.  scrollTop(0) or scrollTop: 0 is going to set the element to the very beginning.
[Jquery Scroll Top](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Here's a working JSFiddle.  One important thing was to set the area to scrollTop(0) first.  Another was to realize that the element has a defined height of 200 even though there is a bunch more text in the innerbox so I scrolled to 1000 just to be sure I made it to the bottom.

It may not be exactly what you want but it should give you an idea of how to use scrollTop.

http://jsfiddle.net/v98HE/

Comment: Where is the OP doing `.scrollTop(0)`?

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle to be what I'm trying to do (changes (0) to (1000), and (1000) to (-1000), but for some reason in my app, what you did works, and what I did doesn't, even though they both work in the fiddle... I'm trying to figure out what could be the cause.

Comment: @adam tal - if you post the new fiddle you created I'll take a look.

Comment: @Tomalak technically Adam is using the css scrollTop but it works in this case much the same way as jquery's scrollTop().  The biggest problem Adam had was that he was trying to start the scrollTop at the div's height which would just effectively set the scroll to the bottom of the div.  I didn't mean to be confusing but I think it did help Adam.

Comment: I think that you could add more explanation into this answer.

Comment: @kasdega - thanks man. I thought I save the same Fiddle. Updated version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfXb7/

Comment: If you want to scroll backward you wouldn't use -1000 you'd use 0.  Start at 1000 like you do in your fiddle but then do scrollTop: 0 to get back to the beginning.  If this doesn't work in your app then I'm going to have to agree with Tomalak that we need more info about your environment.

Comment: Thanks Kasdega. While both versions (-1000 and 0) work on the Fiddle, using 0 does seem to respond in my app, as opposed to no respond at all the other way. Still, it doesn't seem to work, which I assume now is related to the way my app is built. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Seems like I can get the scroll to work, but I'm having problems with the starting point. I tried using the height of elemets I've loaded into the div, and I tried absolute number that should cover any height (9000 for example), but it only scroll a few hundred pixels up and stops... Is there a way I can force the div to scroll to the top whatever the height is?